# installation error in kvm

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

after installimg kvm ,i can't load guest guest operating system
it shows the following error

> Unable to complete install: 'internal error Process exited while
>   reading console log output: chardev: opening backend "pty" failed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 45, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1622, in do_install
    guest.start_install(False, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1193, in start_install
    start_xml, final_xml, is_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1252, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1346, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error Process exited while reading console log output: chardev: opening backend "pty" failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs for apparmor deny lines, maybe it's it who don't allows to open pty. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/libvirt/+bug/632696